# MDT2010 setup for controlling multiple languages on OS and software

Tags: windows-7, windows-vista, deployment, mdt-2010

I'm setting up an MDT 2010 server with LTI for deployment of Vista and later on Windows 7 where I'm supposed to control atleast 8 different languages of OS and software. I'm also building a webinterface to control all this to make it easy for my production personell to configure each computer to order.

My idea was to under applications and operating systems create folders for every language that I place the correct software under and then create extra fields in the database for selecting this. It would look something like this:

```
    Application
       - English
          - Software 1
             - Installation package
          - Software 2
             - Installation package
          ...
       - Danish
          - Software 1 
             - Installation package
          - Software 2
             - Installation package
          ...
       ...
   Operating Systems
      - English
         - OS image
      - Danish
         - OS image
      ...
```

So on an order it can say English, Software 1 and Software 4, or it can say English, Software bundle 1 where Software bunde 1 consists of Software 2 and Software 4. I only want the need to specify the language once and that the choice of the correct software should be made accordingly. I would also like to have it so that if a software is not found in the specified language, it would automatically fall back to English.

Is this the right way to go?

Comment: What did you end up doing?  Did you set this up via PXE boot?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question... but this sounds like one 'right' way to go as far as I'm concerned.  There must have been some time involved with setting this up, if you actually did set it up as outlined above.  I think there are other ways, such as allow for choices in task sequences, but that may not give the level of customization you seem to be looking for while at the same time balancing the usability (not too many complicated choices) for less technical users.